# Matching a Comma Separated List within Brackets

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following string that would be part of a file name.
[Cast1, Cast2, Cast 3], this string is comma delimited. It would be at the end of a film title and be preceded with either a - or ~

The filename would look like this

(Studio) - Title (Year) **~ [Cast1, Cast2, Cast 3]** the section in bold could be optional

I need a **REGEX** to get the following, I know this can be done with string splitting but I need it in REGEX

- Cast1
- Cast2
- Cast 3

I would like this to be in a named group, so far I have `((?P<CAST>([^,]+)))`
But it includes the opening bracket and closing bracket.

On top of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for, try:

```
[-~]\s*\[(?P<CAST>[^\]]*)\]
```

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8EZqb/1)

1. `[-~]` Matches '-' or '~'.
2. `\s*` Matches zero or more whitespace characters.
3. `\[` Matches '['.
4. `(?P<CAST>[^\]]*)` Matches 0 or more characters that are *not* ']' and captures them in named capture group **CAST**.
5. `\]` Matches ']'.

So the above will capture whatever is between the '[' and ']' characters following a '-' or '~' whether those characters contain commas or not. You cannot have 3 capture groups identically named **CAST**. If you want the individual components of the cast, you will have to do it with string splitting:

```py
import re

s = '(Studio) - Title (Year) ~ [Cast1, Cast2, Cast 3]'
m = re.search(r'[-~]\s*\[(?P<CAST>[^\]]*)\]', s)
if m:
    cast = m.group('CAST')
    print re.split(r',\s*', cast)
```

Prints:

```
['Cast1', 'Cast2', 'Cast 3']
```

If you were running Python 3, you could install the **regex** module from the **PyPi** repository, which has far more capabilities then the builtin **re** module, and then you could execute:

```py
import regex

s = '(Studio) - Title (Year) ~ [Cast1, Cast2, Cast 3]'
for m in regex.finditer(r'(?:[-~]\s*\[|\G(?!\A))\K\s*(?P<CAST>[^,\]]*)(?:[,\]])', s):
    print(m['CAST'])
```

Prints:

```
Cast1
Cast2
Cast 3
```

**But what does that buy you?**